# Names for these traditional craft items in Kyushu

Tags: words, word-requests

What are the Japanese terms for these seemingly traditional craft items in Kyushu?

In winter 2013 I spotted two similar freestanding items and one perhaps-related item hanging over a doorway in the vicinity of Fukuoka, Kyushu:

[image: In Higashi, Fukuoka]

[image: In Munakata]

[image: Hanging over a door in Munakata]

Perhaps they are both regional and seasonal. The one above the door seems the same as part of the 2bd freestanding one. So perhaps there is one word for this particular style/tradition and also one word for the freestanding items and one word for the second item?

My attempts to Google these by describing what I saw proved fruitless.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about object identification, not a question about the Japanese language.

Comment: @istrasci Wrong. A question can be about the Japanese language and also involve identifying objects. Your comment however is not at all about the Japanese language and is only about site toxicity.

Comment: First of all, something is not "toxic" just because you say so.  I personally believe your question is off-topic according to [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796/78) (which is linked from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).  It's a purely objective vote; it's not personal.  But you getting butt-hurt about it doesn't make it "toxic".  And if you really feel so, then flag it and see what the mods say.

Comment: And that's why votes exist; if other people don't agree with me, then your question will remain open and it will all be fine.

Comment: @istrasci A question asking for a Japanese word is clearly a question about the Japanese language. It's toxic in the sense that Stack Exchange is sadly but [widely](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7szv7i/anyone_else_find_the_stack_overflow_community/) [regarded](https://www.quora.com/Is-Stack-Overflow-toxic) to be a [toxic/hostile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg) community. Now to quote your link, *Note that asking a translation question about a cultural item is frowned upon, but so far they have not been closed outright.* Mentioning my "butt" is also not appropriate.

Comment: @hippietrail, conversely, calling istrasci's initial comment "wrong" and an example of "site toxicity" seems inappropriate.  That said, two wrongs don't make a right, and all that.  I also note that your links are about problems over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), which is not about Stack Exchange as a whole, nor about the Japanese Stack Exchange site in particular.  Different communities, different people.

Comment: I'm somewhat on the fence about the state of the question post itself.  This is essentially asking, _"what is this Japanese cultural artifact called?"_ This could be viewed as somewhere between "[We don't do purely cultural questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/801#801)" and "[We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799)".

Comment: As a suggestion, try going to https://images.google.com/ and clicking the rectangular "search by image" icon.  Paste in the URL to your image above. On the next screen, click "Find image source" at the top. Then in the Google search bar at the top of that next screen, next to the tiny thumbnail of your image, add the words `japanese decorations` (no need for quotes) and press Enter. Then in the "Visually similar images" gallery partway down the page, click the top-left image.

Comment: You should see something like [this page](https://bit.ly/3w8Ulx6).

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Well it can't be a translation because I'm not offering a word in any other language. I don't know a word for any of these things in English, and there may very well not be a word for them in English or any other language. I am indeed asking "what is this artefact called. Perhaps a rule is needed against nouns or vocabulary or Japan-specific vocabulary. I wouldn't think that's in the spirit of the culture rule: "The questions need to relate to the language", "the question fundamentally must be about the language, not the culture". I never asked what they are for, only the words.

Comment: It seems the culture rule is either not worded to state what you really want it to mean, or that maybe its original purpose was to avoid the site getting spammed with questions about how to bow or use chopsticks, when questions about Japanese words for such things are specifically, exactly, and quintessentially questions about the Japanese language.

Comment: To put it another way, how strict is the rule? Should it be a one-drop rule where a drop of culture in a question invalidates a question whose body is about Japanese terminology? Or was it originally to keep out questions that weren't about language at all but whose OP's thought this site would be the closest place to ask? I can't see how "culture bad above all linguistic considerations" could be a good rule.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the word for these using AI-based image search.

The are a specific kind of **yorishiro** (依り代, 依代, 憑り代, 憑代) called **kadomatsu** (門松), literally "gate pine".  They are also referred to by the far less common terms **matsukazari** (松飾り), **kazarimatsu** (飾り松), and **tatematsu** (立て松).

I have not found whether there are different words for the two different kinds of kadomatsu however.

Surprisingly I'm not allowed to identify what they are for as that would be against the site rules! So I won't link to any information about what they are.

Comment: I would recognize the second as just  門松 with しめ飾り on it.

Comment: @aguijonazo: Interesting. I got the additional terms from the Japanese Wikipedia article. Hopefully I copied and pasted them correctly between the original and the Google translation. But wouldn't that be 門松飾り rather than just 松飾り?

Comment: 門松 is by far the most common name. I didn't know it's also called 松飾り. What I was referring to is [*shimekazari*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/注連縄#注連飾り).

Comment: @aguijonazo I was looking at other terms by following links from "yorishiro" to see if I could find terms for the upright ones compared to the one hanging over the door but it didn't seem clear to me. Now though your link makes it seem like my bottom photo, the one over the door, would be both **kadomatsu** *and* **shimekazari**. Would that be correct? Oh I see now you meant my second *type of item* and not my second *Japanese term*! So my question is already answered! I think while I was looking at photos and articles of kodamatsu I saw some like my bottom photo. I might look again...

Comment: I'm not completely sure if there are technical terms to distinguish the first two but ordinary native speakers recognize them as both *kadomatsu*  and the bottom one as *shimekazari* only (if they know what it is called). So, if I had to explain how the middle one is different from the top one, I would say it's *kadomatsu* with *shimekazari* on it. By the way, *yorishiro* is not a widely known word.

Comment: Ah yes I understand even better now. I think I got "yorishiro" from the English Wikipedia article. I wanted to include all the relevant Japanese words since only the words are permitted. I'm a frequent visitor to Japan but never lived here and since I haven't seen these before I think it's my first time here this time of year.